# Equivalent of signed size_t

Tags: c

If I have something like the following:

```
size_t input_len = strlen(input_str);
signed int match_size = strlen(to) - strlen(from);
```

It's possible that `match_size` can be either zero, positive, or negative. Is there a way to do something like "signed size_t" ? Or is the correct way to do this just saying `int`, or to be more explicit, `signed int` ?

Comment: You probably want [`ptrdiff_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/ptrdiff_t).  `int` is not so good since, for instance, 64-bit systems can easily have strings longer than the largest `int`.

Comment: You're looking for `ssize_t`.

Comment: Note that `ptrdiff_t` is defined by ISO C while `ssize_t` isn't (but is defined by POSIX and is widely available).

Comment: @Shawn I thought `ssize_t` is `size_t` but it allows a `-1` for an error code? Or is it actually used for any kind of "signed size_t" ?

Comment: The first s literally stands for signed.

Comment: @NateEldredge would you suggest using `ptrdiff_t` or `ssize_t` in the above then?

Comment: @carl.hiass: you'd use `ssize_t` as you're computing the difference between two sizes, not two addresses.

Comment: @Shawn `ssize_t` isn't necessarily the signed counterpart of `size_t` despite the type name.

Comment: And `ssize_t` is not part of the C language specification.  It is a POSIXism.

Comment: Careful here folks: `ssize_t` is defined by POSIX as being capable to hold values ranging from `-1` to `_POSIX_SSIZE_MAX` (typically `SIZE_MAX - 1`). It is ***not*** the appropriate type to use for a generic difference of sizes. It is ***not*** the signed counterpart of `size_t`, it is simply a fancier `size_t` with 1 less capacity and an added special value of `-1` for error.

Comment: has everyone forgotten about the xor operator?

Comment: unfortunately there's nothing like that in C. In C++ there's [`std::ssize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)

Comment: @phuclv I see, in lieu of that what would you use, just `singed int` ?

Comment: no, `ssize_t` would be appropriate for many cases. Otherwise use `long long` or `intmax_t` instead

Answer (score 2):

There's not a signed equivalent of `size_t` defined in the C standard.

And no, POSIX's `ssize_t` isn't defined to be "signed size_t", either (even if it was, it wouldn't be able to represent all `size_t` values).
So this gets a bit tricky.

`strlen(to) - strlen(from);` yields another `size_t`. Using another type, such as `ssize_t`, for storing the result could potentially truncate (e.g. if a narrower type is used).

Even the largest signed integer type `intmax_t` isn't guaranteed to be able to hold a `size_t`.

```
size_t to_len = strlen(to);
size_t from_len = strlen(from);

size_t diff = to_len > from_len ? to_len - from_len : from_len - to_len;
```

Then work with `diff` to do whatever you intended.

With `to_len` and `from_len`, you can deduce the "sign" of the difference if needed.

Comment: I see, thanks for this. Why would you suggest using the un-signed `size_t` (with the sign outside it if needed), rather than just doing `signed int` or `signed long long` something like that?

Comment: @carl.hiass simply, you cannot guarantee that `signed long long diff = a - b;` doesn't overflow when `a` and `b` are `size_t`. Simple example: `a = 0; b = SIZE_MAX;` now `a - b` is `< LLONG_MIN`. Overflow causes undefined behavior, so you *must* avoid it. The only general way to do this is comparing the values and doing the right subtraction to get a positive value.

Comment: @carl.hiass The main issue is that whether `int` or `signed long long` or any other signed can hold the range of values that a `size_t` can hold. As explained, there's no data type that's guaranteed to be able to. Aslo refer Macro's example: `0 - SIZE_MAX`.